# cannot read property from angularjs factory

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

I am trying to send a request to sessionFactory to set session details and set actions on success. But I am getting error as "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". Below is my factory and controller code.

**Controller Code**

```
'use strict'; 

myApp.controller('userController',['sessionFactory','$scope', '$http','$rootScope','$state', '$stateParams', function (sessionFactory,$scope,$http,$rootScope,$state, $stateParams) {
$scope.login = function(){
    var credentials = {email:$scope.user.email,password:$scope.user.password,action:'login'};
    $http.post($rootScope.baseURL+'assets/api/user.php',credentials)
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
            if(data == 'false'){
                $scope.signinError = "username and password does not match";
            }
            else {
                $('#signInModal').modal('hide');
                sessionFactory.set(data).then(function(response){
                console.log(response);

                });
        }
    });
}
}]);
```

**The factory code is**

```
myApp.factory('sessionFactory',function($http,$rootScope){

   var session = {};

session.set = function(data){

    var credentials = data;
        credentials['action']='set';
          $http.post($rootScope.baseURL+'assets/api/session.php',credentials) //Sets session variables in server side.
          .success(function(response){
              if(response){
                    angular.forEach(response,function(value, key){
                    sessionStorage.setItem(key, value); //sets session variables in client side.

            });  
              }
              return response;
          });


}

return session;
```

});

Comment: This is happening because your function returning response not the promise.

Comment: Should i use deferred = $q.defer in factory.

Comment: no then it will be anti pattern you already have a promise of $http :-)
Just return $http.post($rootScope.baseURL+'assets/api/session.php',credentials)  and handle further things inside the controller :-)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To close question @squiroid's answer:

> return `$http.post($rootScope.baseURL+'assets/api/session.php',credentials)` and handle further things inside the controller